# How can I change the default font and text size settings for Chrome's reader-mode flag?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome's`#enable-reader-mode` flag is quite useful.  However, I would like to change the default text size.  By clicking the settings in the top right corner, I can change the font, text-size, and background colour for the page I am viewing at that moment.  However, these settings have no effect on future pages (including future uses of reader mode on the same page).  Is there anyway to make changes stick?